# Mongo errno:111 Connection refused (ubuntu)?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

my mongod service is unable to start i try all the solution available i tried following commands

- sudo rm /var/lib/mongod/mongod.lock
- sudo service mongod start
- sudo service mongod restart

but still get the following error :-

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19
>   connecting to: test
>   2018-07-23T04:49:02.322+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
>   2018-07-23T04:49:02.322+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
>   @(connect):1:6
>
> exception: connect failed

Comment: did you try **mongod --repair** flag ?

Comment: yes i did it does not work at all